# Filter by maptype value in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Spark dataframe:

```
Text_col             Maptype_col
what is SO           {3:1, 5:1, 1:1}
what is spark        {3:2, 5:1}
```

I want to filter (remove) rows where at least one entry in the Maptype_col has a value greater than 1.

I have written the following code, but the value in click_filter is null for each row:

```
@udf(returnType=BooleanType())
def filter_map(col_map):
    retval = 0
    for k in col_map:
        if col_map[k] > 1: retval = 1
    return retval

newudf = origudf.withColumn("filtered_map"),  filter_map(F.col("Maptype_col"))
```

The output is:

```
Text_col             Maptype_col       filtered_map
what is SO           {3:1, 5:1, 1:1}   null
what is spark        {3:2, 5:1}        null
```

Expected output:

```
Text_col             Maptype_col       filtered_map
what is SO           {3:1, 5:1, 1:1}   0
what is spark        {3:2, 5:1}        1
```

Comment: what is your expected output ?

Comment: Updated the post with expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map_filter` function, like below.

```
df
.withColumn(
    "filtered_map", 
    expr("size(map_filter(Maptype_col, (k, v) -> v > 1 ))")
)
```

```
+-------------+------------------------+------------+
|Text_col     |Maptype_col             |filtered_map|
+-------------+------------------------+------------+
|what is S0   |{3 -> 1, 5 -> 1, 1 -> 1}|0           |
|what is spark|{3 -> 2, 5 -> 1}        |1           |
+-------------+------------------------+------------+
```